# how to change multer express post headers?

Tags: javascript, html, express, multer

I have a node/express app and I want to add an image upload to an order form.

I can get the html form to POST using the action link, but I also want my javascript file for this page to be able to take all the rest of the form data and send it to a different post route to create a database entry for the whole order.

Here is my HTML that works for sending the post and image, but reloads the page because of event default behaviour.

```
<form id="editOrderForm" method="POST" action="/uploadphoto" enctype='multipart/form-data' >

                        <div class="form-row">
                          <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                            <label for="orderWarranty">Warranty Type</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="orderWarranty" placeholder="Warranty Type">
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                            <label for="orderAppliance">Appliance</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="orderAppliance" placeholder="Appliance">
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                            <label for="orderBrand">Brand</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="orderBrand" placeholder="Brand">
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                            <label for="orderModel">Model</label>
                            <input type="text" id="orderModel" class="form-control" placeholder="">
                          </div>
                        </div>

  <div class="modal-body mx-6" id="editOrderDiv">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label for="image-upload">Upload Image</label>
       <input type="file" accept="image/*" id="imageupload" name="imageupload">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="ordersubmit"></input>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

What I need is for the below code to ALSO run after the form submits, to make another post.

If I try to post to my upload route from my js file it sends the post with a content-type of application/x-www-form-urlencoded instead of multipart/form-data no matter what I do, so multer doesnt accept it.

Is there a way to set the content-type before I send the request to the backend?

```
$("#editOrderForm").on("submit", function handleFormSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    function submitOrder(Order) {
      $.post("/api/orders/" + currentOrder.id, Order, function () {
        getOrders(orderCategorySelect.val());
      });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really use jQuery, but I think you want to create a headers object in the call to `$.post`.

Check out [the jquery docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), which also refers to [the ajax settings](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings).

From skimming the docs, it sounds like you need to create an Ajax request with the correct header in the settings, and then use that request to do the actual POST.

Something like:

```
let request = $.post({
  "header" : "multipart/form-data"
})

request("/api/orders", [rest of code here])
```